# Hodge structure of relative cohomology groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hodge-theory

I need a hint or a good reference for definition of mixed Hodge structure on the relative cohomology groups ($\mathrm{H}^*(X,Y)$, $Y\subset X$ a closed subvariety of a comolex quasiprojective variety $X$, or even(?) $Y$ is a cycle (formal sum of subvarities) in $X$ ).

Thanks!

Comment: This is even easier than the complement: just consider the kernel of the restriction map $\Omega^*(X)\to\Omega^*(Y)$; it computes what you want and, by Deligne, it has a mixed Hodge structure.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev You mean to consider the Hodge complex structure on the kernel? Does there exist a simpler way?

Comment: What can possibly be simpler? You don't even need logarithmic differentials! And, of course, this is all described in Deligne's three papers very nicely.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that *the* reference is Deligne, Théorie de Hodge III, 8.3.8. Also see section 5.5 of Peters and Steenbrink's book on Mixed Hodge structures.